# Regroup variables

Tags: r

I am trying to reorganise the categories in my variable (var) to make it binary.

Right now the variable contains 11 categories 0-10 and you can see value counts for each category below:

```
> table(mydf$var)
0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10  
61   59  111  259  277  959  280  259  151   28   53
```

I want to group the two extremes together so that values 0-2 and 8-9 = 0 and values 3-7 = 1

What's the best way to do this without creating new variables?

Answer (score 1):

A choice using `findInterval()`:

```r
x <- 0:10
y <- +(findInterval(x, c(3, 8)) == 1)

y
# [1] 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0
```